Default password for Oracle FreeBSD 14.2 image
I’m trying to set up an Oracle instance with FreeBSD-14.2 on amd64 and I’m not able to figure out the password for the root or freebsd users.
I can’t find the passwords documented anywhere, and I’ve tried every password I can think of (no password, root, toor, freebsd, hunter2…). The FreeBSD 14.2-RC1 announcement email says the accounts/passwords should be root/root and freebsd/freebsd, but those aren’t working for me on the image.
I'm trying to log in via the console in Oracle Cloud's web interface. I was able to log in via ssh, but when I run passwd it asks me for the old password and I don't know the old password.

I got in touch with Dave Cottlehuber, who created the FreeBSD-14.2 image for Oracle Cloud. He was very helpful and let me know that the root and freebsd user both don't have a password set. The problem I was encountering was because Oracle requires that the root and freebsd user have console logins disabled by default. He pointed me at the config file that creates the image.
The only way to access the machine is to add a SSH key when creating the instance. You can then ssh to the machine as the freebsd user and run sudo.
If you want to be able to access your instance via the console you'll need to either set a password on the freebsd user (sudo passwd freebsd) or create a new user with a password.
